# HTTP Request 'delete' in Rails testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm following along the [Michael Hartl Rails tutorial chapter 8](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out) on authentication and I've run into an error. In listing 8.28 we add code to our integration test to test logging out a user. This involves sending a 'delete' HTTP Request. After running this test, the result should be GREEN, but I run into the following error:

> ERROR["test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout",
>   UsersLoginTest, 2015-04-15 03:20:30 +0000] 
>   test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout#UsersLoginTest
>   (1429068030.89s) AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
>   AbstractController::ActionNotFound: **The action 'delete' could not be
>   found for SessionsController**
>               test/integration/users_login_test.rb:28:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
>           test/integration/users_login_test.rb:28:in`block in '

I haven't been able to find anything on this issue. Does anyone have any ideas what's causing this? For the record I'm using the Cloud 9 IDE recommended by Michael Hartl in the tutorial.

Route file as requested:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root              'static_pages#home'
  get 'help' =>     'static_pages#help'
  get 'about' =>    'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' =>  'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup' =>   'users#new'
  get 'login' =>    'sessions#new'
  post 'login' =>   'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout' =>'sessions#delete'
  resources :users
end
```

Comment: please post your route file

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed where the mistake was!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route:

```
 delete 'logout' =>'sessions#delete'
```

Should be:

```
 delete 'logout' =>'sessions#destroy'
```